# Google Re-captcha 2 keyboard accessibility

Tags: accessibility, recaptcha, wcag2.0

I have implemented Google Re-Captcha 2 on a login form for a website and am currently doing accessibility testing on it (particularly in regards to simulating the experience as a blind user).

I find that although there is a "voice over" option to complete when challenged, I cannot seem to give focus to the modal window that pops up with my keyboard to launch the voice option.  I thought this might be a problem with my site, but I have tried it with a plain HTML page, and get the same issue.

I've looked online, and Google mentions that you can click the voice option (which you can), but I don't see the point of that if you are visually impaired (if I could see that small voice button, I could see the rest of the captcha).

Does anyone know if this is an existing issue with Google Re-captcha 2?  Is Google Re-Captcha 2 not supposed to be keyboard accessible?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have been a temporary defect with the Re-Captcha 2.  It appears that google has provided a fix, as it is now working on all of the sites that I have deployed it too.